# Error while installing spacy

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, anaconda, spacy

Error while finding module specification for

```
'spacy.en.download'

(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.en')
```

I'm getting this error while executing

```
    python -m spacy.en.download
```

Comment: try `pip install spacy` then `python -m spacy download en` always good to read the docs. https://spacy.io/usage/

Comment: I ran these commands before downloading the en module                    
"conda create -n spacy python
activate spacy
conda install spacy"

Comment: try `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`

Comment: I updated Visual C++ build tools and it worked. Visual C++ Build tools was a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue got resolved.

```
python -m spacy.en.download
```

works only if the installation folder has admin rights. If your installation folder doesn't have admin rights, try this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load(<spacy model you wish to use>)
```

To know more about various spacy models refer: https://spacy.io/models/

Answer (score 1):

You should probably install spacy first before executing a module `spacy.en.download` from it.

Before your command run: `conda install spacy`

Answer (score 0):

Try this with admin rights:

`python -m spacy download en`